# Nagios - Can't access the hosts and services on nagios web interface

Tags: linux, centos, nagios

I'm trying to install Nagios. I'm using an AMI on Amazon CentOS which installs Ambari + Nagios + ... Everything works fine except Nagios interface.

Nagios is running without any trouble.
But, when I try to access to the web interface, if I go on any link on the right, I always get the message :

```
Whoops!

Error: Could not read object configuration data!

Here are some things you should check in order to resolve this error:

Verify configuration options using the -v command-line option to check for errors.
Check the Nagios log file for messages relating to startup or status data errors.
Make sure you read the documentation on installing, configuring and running Nagios thoroughly before continuing. If all else fails, try sending a message to one of the mailing lists. More information can be found at http://www.nagios.org.
```

I've runned the command /usr/sbin/nagios -v /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg

```
...
Checking for circular paths between hosts...
Checking for circular host and service dependencies...
Checking global event handlers...
Checking obsessive compulsive processor commands...
Checking misc settings...

Total Warnings: 2
Total Errors:   0
```

I've also checked the permissions (my apache is running with user apache and group nagios) on   /usr/lib/nagios/cgi/, /usr/share/nagios and /usr/lib64/nagios (everything is in the group nagios).
I've also checked the files status.dat and objects.cache in /var/nagios/ .

I really can't find where's the problem... Can somebody help me plz ?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall nagios only?

Comment: @Max It seems that's the only solution I have left. But I'd rather find an other one...

Comment: Ok, I finally found the problem. The config was wrong (even if the check succeeded) because some int values are set with 0.5 by Ambari.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found the problem. The config was wrong (even if the check succeeded) because some int values are set with 0.5 by Ambari. – nimporte51